# Is there anyway compile from jade to twig file?

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, twig, pug

I currently working on twig files on my project but I still want to use jade syntax. I also use Laravel Elixir to compile jade file. The problem is when compile jade file, it only compiles into file **.blade.php** in Laravel. So is there anyway that I can generate from jade to **.twig** file? I'm using npm package called *laravel-elixir-jade*.
Here is my Gulpfile.js

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix
    .sass(''+sassPath+'*.*', ''+cssPath+'style.css' )
    .scripts(''+jsPath+'*.*', ''+jsCopyPath+'main.js')
    .jade({
        search: '*.jade',
        src: '/resources/jade/'
    })
    .browserSync({
            files: [
            ''+cssPath+'**/*', // Watch css files for changes
            ''+jsPath+'**/*',  // Watch js files for changes
            ''+twigPath+'**/*' // Watch twig files for changes
            ],
            proxy: 'http://dev.myproject.com'
            });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check [this](https://github.com/naltatis/jade-to-twig). But I think that use jade and twig together is unnecessary complicated.

Comment: I've used this package already but it seems does not work to me. Maybe I will try it again.